# Not able to select text in textbox

Tags: asp.net, textbox

I've got this here wizard step with a couple of text boxes.  For some reason I cannot highlight/select the text in the textbox in IE or FF and I have no idea why, not even after spending a couple of hours googling the problem.  I could really use another set of eyes on this.  Let me know if you need more code to help.

```
<asp:WizardStep ID="wsPlanInfo" runat="server" Title="" StepType="Step">
                    <div style="width:100%; height:290px; margin-top:150px ">
                        <table border="0" style="margin:0 auto;">
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" class="title">
                                    Placeholder text here?
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2"><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtLearningPlanName" Width="300px" CssClass="input-text"  /> <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rflLearningPlanName" ControlToValidate="txtLearningPlanName" ErrorMessage="*" CssClass="validator" /><br /><br /></td>
                            </tr>
                             <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" class="title">
                                    placeholder text here?
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                             <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>
                                    <table border="0"><tr><td><asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rbSpecificDate" GroupName="DeadlinePicker" Checked="true" /></td><td><UC:DatePicker runat="server" ID="ucSpecificDatePicker" RequiredField="false" /></td></tr></table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                             <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rbCustomUserFieldPlusDays" GroupName="DeadlinePicker" /> <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlUserCustomFields" CssClass="input-text" /> plus <Telerik:RadNumericTextBox runat="server" SkinID="Normal" ID="rntbUserCustomFieldOffset" ShowSpinButtons="true" DataType="System.Int32" NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="0" Width="60px" Value="365" /> days
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                             <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rbPlusDays" GroupName="DeadlinePicker" /> <Telerik:RadNumericTextBox runat="server" SkinID="Normal" ID="rntbPlusDays" ShowSpinButtons="true" DataType="System.Int32" NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="0" Width="60px" Value="365" /> days from today
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                             <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rbNone" GroupName="DeadlinePicker" /> None
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                       </table>
                    </div>
                </asp:WizardStep>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `disableSelection(document.body)` in my javascript solved my problem.  Note to self, post entire code when asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
((TextBox)wsPlanInfo.FindControl("txtLearningPlanName")).Text
```

It will search the `Wizard Step's` Control list for a textbox with that `ID` name. It then casts it as a `TextBox` and so you can then use the `Text` property.

Comment: 2 questions to your answer 1)if I want to add all the text boxes in the step would I use ((TextBox)wsPlanInfo.FindControl("txtLearningPlanName","2ndTextBox","3rdTextBox")).Text? 2)being a no0b I'm not quite sure where to put this code...somewhere in the code behind I'm guessing?

Comment: No, you can't add each textbox into that one call. You'll have to do it for each control you want to. Or, you can use a `foreach` loop and go through each one. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) You can put this code in your code-behind, wherever you want to get the text information. For example, on a `submit` button you have, you can place it in the button's event handler.

Comment: When I try to insert this like so `protected void Page_Load(object send, EventArgs e) {((TextBox)wsPlanInfo.FindControl("txtLearningPlanName")).Text;}` I get a "this expression is not valid error"

Comment: Split it up and see. `var tb = wsPlanInfo.FindControl("txtLearningPlanName") as TextBox; string text = tb.Text;`